# Rotate camera based on mouse postitions around a object Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Okay, So I have come this far:

```
public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour {

public void RotateCamera()
    {
        float x = 5 * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float y = 5 * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        Camera.mainCamera.transform.parent.transform.Rotate (y,x,0);
    }

}
```

My camera has a parent which I rotate based on my mouse position. The only problem is that I can only swipe with the mouse to rotate the object. How can I rotate the object which is my camera is attached to based on my mouse position if I just click next to the object. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The value will be in the range -1...1 for keyboard and joystick input.
>   If the axis is setup to be delta mouse movement, the mouse delta is
>   multiplied by the axis sensitivity and the range is not -1...1. [Unity Document](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html)

Note: This [link](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=LookAtMouse) is usefull please check it.

So you need to change your code like this.

```
public void RotateCamera()
{
    Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); // Gets mouse position to Unity World coordinate system
    Camera.mainCamera.transform.parent.transform.Rotate (mousePosition);
}
```

if there are problem you can do like this

```
public void RotateCamera()
{
    Vector3 position = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y,0);
    Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position); // Gets mouse position to Unity World coordinate system
    Camera.mainCamera.transform.parent.transform.Rotate (mousePosition);
}
```

one more option is [rotateTowards](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html).

```
public float speed=10; //any value > 0
public void RotateCamera()
{
    Vector3 targetDir = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - Camera.mainCamera.transform.parent.transform.position;
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    Vector3 newDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDir, step, 0.0F);
    Camera.mainCamera.transform.parent.transform.rotation =  Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir);
}
```

Maybe some syntax errors, i don't check them.