# How can I use sin and cos for rotation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, trigonometry

Okay, so this is my code:

```
float temp1 = Mathf.Sin(Input.mousePosition.x - Screen.width / 2);
float temp2 = Mathf.Cos(Input.mousePosition.y - Screen.height / 2);
Camera.mainCamera.transform.parent.transform.Rotate(temp1,temp2,0);
```

So I am trying to rotate the parent of my camera based on the angle between my mouse and the parent of the camera. Except I am doing something wrong can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well you probably need parentheses around the subtractions. Division has higher precedence.

Comment: Ok so I did that but now it turns in the exact opposite direction

Comment: 1) suspect you want `float angle = arctan2f(Input.mousePosition.y - Screen.height / 2, Input.mousePosition.x - Screen.width / 2); (Change radians to degrees if needed) Camera.mainCamera.transform.parent.transform.Rotate(angle);`.  But this is outside my [wheelhouse](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wheelhouse).

Comment: Suggest adding tag `Unity3D` to the post instead of the title.

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/q/28397558/2410359

Comment: Yes I am working on a project and that was good for then but now it has to be like this. And I updated the tag. And yes it should look somthing like that code except that Rotate() needs an x and y thats why I use the sin and cos but I cant seem to get it right haha.

Comment: mouse.x - midwidth is already the cos (times radius) and mouse.y-midheigth is already the sin (times radius), so it does not make sense to sin/cos them again !
Rotate expect 3 angles, in degrees. so just take mouse-midscreen and scale it down if you want to map screen width/height wide motion to 360° rather than screensize°.

Answer (score 0):

```
float temp1 = Mathf.Cos(  (Input.mousePosition.x - Screen.width) / 2 );
float temp2 = Mathf.Sin( -(Input.mousePosition.y - Screen.height) / 2);
Camera.mainCamera.transform.parent.transform.Rotate(temp1, temp2, 0);
```

Comment: It still turns in random directions, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Because x and y are measured from top-left? That's just my guess.

Comment: Well looking closer I see that you probably have the sin() and cos() reversed too.

Comment: `code float temp1 = Mathf.Cos( (Input.mousePosition.x - Screen.width) / 2 );
float temp2 = Mathf.Sin( (Screen.height - Input.mousePosition.y) / 2);
Camera.mainCamera.transform.parent.transform.Rotate(temp1, temp2, 0);`

Comment: I don't know how to use that Rotate function but I saw another link that had (y, x). So reverse the temp1 and temp2 values.

Comment: So what are the arguments to Rotate() supposed to mean?

Comment: O sorry I havent said that I am working in unity. This is the rotate function http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Comment: Yeah, I had pretty much figured that out. (x, y, z) looks right but I don't know what's going on. I don't know anything about Unity.